# Help me to understand the output signal of this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, diodes

I want to understand the output voltage of this circuit.

My analysis is:

- When we are in the positive half of the wave, the capacitor will charge and the current will flow through D1 after it goes to the source, so in the first half the Vout will be zero.
- When we are in the negative half, D1 is reverse biased so the current will go to the capacitor after it goes to vout and there will be +10V at point of Vout, but the simulation results show that it will be -10V and it decreases more and more. I can't understand why.

Can someone help me understand this circuit?

[image]

Comment: Flipp both D1 and D2 diode connections. And you will get the positive voltage at the output. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCAhs.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a voltage doubler.
On the positive half of the waveform C1 charges through D1. On the negative half C2 charges through C1 and D2, so the voltage on C1 is added to the supply voltage and C2 charges to ~ 2 X V1.

The stairstep type output is simply because it takes a number of cycles for the caps to charge to the maximum values.

This is configured for a negative output voltage, swap the diode and capacitor polarities (if electrolytics are used) for a positive output.

Comment: thank you so much i get it now